# Combobox preenchida no formulário de edição

Tags: php, html

como faço para carregar essa combobox preenchida no formulário de edição com o valor escolhido durante o cadastro?

```html
<label for="tipo_lancamento">tipo de lancamento</lable>
<select name="tipo_lancamento">
        <option></option>
    <option value="receita">receita</option>
    <option value="despesa">despesa</option>
</select><br/>
```

Consigo carregar os inputs preenchidos através do seguinte código, porém esta opção não funciona junto a combobox

```html
<label for="pessoa">Pessoa</label><br />
<input type="text" name="pessoa" id="pessoa" value="<?=$lancamento['pessoa'];?>"  required />
```

Comment: Você quer deixar selecionado o valor que vem da sua tag ´select´ é isso ?

Comment: Olá Ricardo, teria que deixar selecionado valor que foi salvo no banco durante o cadastro, porém como é um form de edição, teria que vim a outra opção, caso o usuário queria mudar, desde já agradeço o feedback

Answer (score 0):

Bom pessoal, consegui através de um post que encontrei nesse blog http://wbruno.com.br/php/mostrar-option-de-select-escolhido-pelo-usuario-php-mysql/, estou postando a solução, pois acredito que outro usuário possa ter a mesma dificuldade que encontrei. No meu caso, entendi como funciona e adaptei a minha necessidade

1º foi declarado uma função, para evitar duplicação de código.

```html
<?php
function selected( $value, $selected ){
    return $value==$selected ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
}
```

2º depois uso ela em cada um dos meus options:

```html
<select name="tipo_lancamento">
  <option value="Despesa"<?php echo selected( 'Despesa', $lancamento['tipo_lancamento'] ); ?>>Despesa</option>
 <option value="Receita"<?php echo selected( 'Receita', $lancamento['tipo_lancamento'] ); ?>>Receita</option>
</select>
```